# I cannot add the command line on my app editor app on elementary hera

Tags: applications, release-hera

[image]

i already add the link by paste it but i cant save it

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `file://` part of the command, so that it becomes `/home/ghozi56/.Application/Leonflix.AppImage`?